# Implement overload with differents return types

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I need to overload a method with two differents return types, and in java is not possible, so does it make sense if i have a super class with "Object" return type
an then i override this method in two different classes?

```
class A{
    Object method()
    {
    ...
    }
}

class B extends A{
    @Override
    Integer method()
    {
    ...
    }
}

class C extends A{
    @Override
    Double method()
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

or is there a better way to do this? or simply other solutions?

Comment: Don't overload and give the methods a different name ... ?

Comment: @RobinTopper Not necessarily after 1.5.

Comment: Actually i would have a List<A> and then call the method() and return a type according to the input, for example if the input is a string with length>2 return Integer, otherwise return Double.

Comment: What about returning `Number` instead of `Object` ?

Comment: @RudiDudi: Aren't there 100 integers whose string rendering in decimal has a length <= 2? (Roughly speaking, more if you're allowing negatives. ;-) )

Comment: It was just an example, In reality i need to return a list<D> if the input is a certain type and return a String if is not.

Comment: what "input" ? that does not sound like an override use-case, more like an overload or generics one...

Comment: Overloading and overriding have little to do with each other. It's not clear what your scenario is and why you think one could substitute for the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> so does it make sense if i have a super class with "Object" return type an then i override this method in two different classes?

Yes. That is why [`Covariant return types`](https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/covariant-return-types-in-java) got introduced from Java 1.5.

> Before 1.5, overriding method can't have different return type. This is relaxed in 1.5. The subclass method's return type R2 may be different from superclass method's return type R1, but R2 should be a subtype of R1. i.e., subclass can return type may be a subtype of superclass return type.

Comment: *Blech*. But I guess I can see it... :-) I certainly wouldn't do it without a darned fine reason.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ha ha. I can feel you. Tried to think a real world example for 5 min and no luck.

Comment: Real-world uses are very common in my experience. Off the top of my head, I know Guava uses it all over.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i would say you have to convince yourself first why you want to go for `overriding` if they have different return types and not sub classes. I don't think that's a best use case for overriding.

You should go for method `overloading` instead. You don't have to unnecessary substitute `overloading` with overriding.